# Add pagination on the "reqs" page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I went to the `reqs` tab from the meta homepage and I noticed that I was not able to paginate. Now, this really isn't that big of a deal, but there are two problems:

1. It is ordered by votes, which means that you're likely to only see questions which were originally authored months, if not years ago. Personally, I view this as the real UI issue, but...
2. It is counter-intuitive. One thing I think that SE has tried really hard to do is to make things as intuitive as possible, and this isn't.

Proposed solutions:

- Have `reqs` simply link to the `feature-request` tab. I don't know how hard this would be, but it seems like it would be the most intuitive.
- Order the page by recent activity and not by votes/question.
- Have pagination on that page. I dislike this as I view it as inconsistent with the way that page normally works without adding benefiting the page much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need, just search for

`[feature-request] -[status-completed] -[status-declined]`

(add other not tags to taste, etc)

edit: good point, we should add the helpful text at the bottom offering the complete list.

Comment: There might be a point in putting this link at the bottom of the list, similar to the main page. Or simply [doing this search (with sort=votes)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined?sort=votes) instead of the current `reqs` tab. (The same is valid for "bugs").

Comment: Here's a question for data.SE. How much of Jeff's rep. is based on "status-..." answers?